# What is the difference in the data consumed in unicast vs broadcast using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, networking, websocket, socket.io

If I send a 10KB message to 10,000 clients using socket.io broadcast then will the server consume a bandwidth of 10 * 10,000 KB or just 10KB?

Comment: Broadcasts are sent once, so it makes no difference to the sender's bandwidth consumption. However it makes a difference to the clients, as they all have to get the packet up to the UDP layer even if they aren't listening to broadcasts. This is one of the advantages of multicast.

Comment: How does multicast work in socket.io? Please explain .